How to pass a Flutter blue plus BluetoothDevice to an isolate (BLE)?
I currently having an issue with passing a BluetoothDevice to an isolate in flutter.
Note: I am currently using the flutter_blue_plus package to handle BLE operations within the application. Flutter Blue Plus
Requisites
BLE Devices
Let's start off on why I need to use an isolate. Currently, the application requires that the user connects to two BLE devices;

First BLE device utilizes GATT characteristics to transmit its data
directly using its aforementioned characteristics
The Second is using GATT characteristics with its own BLE protocol.

The Second device is what I am struggling with. It has four characteristics and currently I only have to use one of them. ABF1 is used to write and read data from the device.
while (isotpBleDevice.device.isConnected == true) {Do Device processes}

This device requires a while loop, meaning that flutter's main isolate will start to jank or "freeze" when the user does correctly connect to this BLE device. The while loop continues based on the connection status of the device.
Isolates
An isolate is basically a new thread on flutter that has its own enclosed memory, meaning that it does not share data with the main isolate on the application (The main flutter thread). If you would like to read up on this or review flutter isolates, refer to this: Flutter Isolates
When should we actually use an Isolate?

Large computations and or I/O operations
When async functions are not sufficient for the process
General large process optimization

So from my understanding of isolates, AI assistance, and documentation; I need to implement an isolate to allow the Second BLE device to run concurrently with the application and provide data back to the user. I.E I need to implement an isolate to allow the Second BLE device to proceed with its own processes whilst allowing data to be passed back to the main isolate to display appropriate data to the user.
From my understanding and the need to obtain data back from the isolate. I need to spawn an isolate:

Future spawn(
void entryPoint(
T message
),
T message,
{bool paused = false,
bool errorsAreFatal = true,
SendPort? onExit,
SendPort? onError,
@Since("2.3") String? debugName}
)

My Implementation
Isolate Arguments Class

    class ISOTP_Isolate_Args {
      final SendPort sendPort;
      final List<String> debugMessages;
      final BluetoothDevice device;
    
      ISOTP_Isolate_Args(this.sendPort, this.debugMessages, this.device);
    }


The class acts as a type safe implementation of passing the parameters to the Isolate.
Where the isolate is being spawned

    //Method to run the ISOTP Isolate / cause multithreading on the device
      Future<void> run_ISOTP_BLE_device(ConnectedDevice connectedDevice) async {
        await DebugFile.instance
            .log("Connected device passed: ${connectedDevice.device.platformName}");
        //Create a receive port to listen for messages from the spawned isolate
        final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
    
        try {
          //Create an array of string to store debug messages for the isolate and then just return it later and append to the debug file
          List<String> debugMessages = [];
          //Listen for message sent from the spawned isolate
          receivePort.listen((message) async {
            //Handle the received message
            await DebugFile.instance
                .log("Received a message from the listen callback");
            //Assign the global instance of the debug file to this
            for (var i = 0; i < (message as List<String>).length; i++) {
              await DebugFile.instance.log((message as List<String>)[i]);
            }
          });
    
          ISOTP_Isolate_Args isotp_isolate_args = ISOTP_Isolate_Args(
              receivePort.sendPort, debugMessages, connectedDevice.device);
          //Start new isolate to continuously run the ISOTP BLE Actions without potential problems. It returns a closure rather than any data.
          await Isolate.spawn(
            do_Continuous_ISOTP_BLE_Actions,
            isotp_isolate_args,
            errorsAreFatal: true,
          );
    
          await DebugFile.instance.log("The isolate has been created");
        } catch (e) {
          //Handle an unexpected error
          await DebugFile.instance
              .log("Error starting the ISOTP BLE Isolate: ${e}");
        } finally {
          ConnectedDevice? isotpDevice = connectedDevice;
          if (isotpDevice != null) {
            if (isotpDevice.device.isDisconnected) {
              //Close the receive port to prevent resource leaks
              receivePort.close();
    
              await DebugFile.instance.log("The isolate has been destroyed");
            }
          }
        }
      } 


The run_ISOTP_BLE_Device starts when the application successfully connects to the Second device. This spawns the Isolate to run the BLE procesess.
Isolate running code
//Run ISOTP BLE in an ISOLATE
  void do_Continuous_ISOTP_BLE_Actions(
      ISOTP_Isolate_Args isotp_isolate_args) async {
    //Assign the isolate memory to the passed isolate variables
    final SendPort sendPort = isotp_isolate_args.sendPort;

    debuggingMessages = isotp_isolate_args.debugMessages;

    BluetoothDevice device = isotp_isolate_args.device;

    ISOTP_device = ConnectedDevice.fromDevice(device);

    debuggingMessages
        .add("The obtained connected device: ${device.platformName}");
    //Send back the debugfile instance
    sendPort.send(debuggingMessages);
    //Reset the debugMessages after being sent
    debuggingMessages.clear();
}

Here is the base implementation of the code. I keep getting a null, empty string, or "nothing". A potential solution might be that I need to serialize the BluetoothDevice before passing it to the isolate.
And yes, I know that the singleton classes cannot be accessed in the isolate as the isolate has its own memory, separated from the main isolate so I can't access the singleton instance of DebugFile in the spawned isolate.
What can I try next? I can't wrap my head around the fact that I can pass the sendPort and the debugMessages and get values whilst just getting a null for the passed BluetoothDevice.
